# How to apply a collapsed revisions patch to trunk in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I am looking for best practices to do the following:

When I need to implement a feature or fix a bug, I am creating new Mercurial repository from the main one (a trunk).
Then, within some days, or weeks, I am implementing the task in newly created repository, making commits and **periodically merging with trunk**. After the code in new repository will pass all code reviews, I should provide a repository with all changes collapsed into single revision.

My common way to do this ([rdiff extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RdiffExtension) should be enabled):

```
hg clone ~/repos/trunk ~/repos/new-collapsed
cd ~/repos/new-collapsed
hg diff ~/repos/new > new.diff
patch -p1 < new.diff
hg commit
```

This works almost well except when there are binary files present in the changes from ~/repos/new. Another way could be:

```
hg clone ~/repos/trunk ~/repos/new-collapsed
cd ~/repos/new-collapsed
hg pull ~/repos/new
hg update
hg rollback
then resolve possible conflicts and manually commit the changes
```

Both ways look for me somewhat ugly and non-native, so I am looking how this operation could be simplified. I've played with [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseProject), but seems its `hg rebase --collapse` command does not work with workflow described above.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** Just add

```
[diff]
git = True
```

to your hgrc file, and then use my first solution with rdiff extension, replacing `patch` with `hg import`:

```
hg clone ~/repos/trunk ~/repos/new-collapsed
cd ~/repos/new-collapsed
hg diff ~/repos/new > new.diff
hg import new.diff
hg commit
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good case for mercurial queues.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar with the [histedit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) extension.

My workflow is something like:

- clone a central repo
- commit incremental changes to local repo
- clone my local repo to make collapsed repo
- `hg histedit` and select/discard/fold the revisions as needed
- `hg push` the collapsed repo to central repo
- pull central repo to local or refresh local from scratch

I ensure that my local repo never gets pushed to the central repo by adding an invalid `default-push` path to the `.hg/hgrc` file in the local repo root directory.

Comment: Hmmm I've looked onto histedit extension some time ago ... usually I have a lot of revisions that should be collapsed (my own record was 600+ commits), so in a lot of cases manual revision manipulating isn't suitable.